# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: text = uuid

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following sqlalchemy model:

```py
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Person'

    index = Column(BigInteger, index=True)
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    first_name = Column(String(50))
    last_name = Column(String(50))
    occupation = Column(String(50))
    dob = Column(Date)
    country = Column(String(30))
```

When I try to query `Person` based on `first_name` and `last_name` as follows:

```py
session.query(Person).filter(and_(
        Person.first_name == request.first_name,
        Person.last_name == request.last_name,
)).first()
```

I got the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: text = uuid
LINE 3: WHERE "Person".id = '7bcc3d89-0660-4d64-adca-620132fe88f8'::...
                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

[SQL: SELECT "Person".index, "Person".id, "Person".first_name, "Person".last_name, "Person".occupation, "Person".dob, "Person".country
FROM "Person"
WHERE "Person".id = %(pk_1)s]
[parameters: {'pk_1': UUID('7bcc3d89-0660-4d64-adca-620132fe88f8')}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

In a similar SA question the suggestion was to cast the datatype of both sides of the comparison in `filter()` to be the same. However, here I'm just trying to find a person info based on `first_name` and `last_name` and `uuid` is not a condition for filtering.

Could you show me a way to solve this? Thank you!

## Edit

Below is my complete error traceback:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53060 - "POST /person HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 404, in run_asgi        
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__        
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\debug.py", line 106, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\debug.py", line 103, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, inner_send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 92, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 147, in simple_response       
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 75, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 64, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__       
    raise e
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__       
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 680, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 275, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 231, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 162, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\project_name\service_name\routes.py", line 29, in create_data
    new_data = services.create_data_in_db(session, request)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\project_name\service_name\services.py", line 29, in create_data_in_db
    session.refresh(new_data)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2338, in refresh
    loading.load_on_ident(
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 407, in load_on_ident
    return load_on_pk_identity(
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 530, in load_on_pk_identity      
    session.execute(
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1712, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1705, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 333, in _execute_on_connection  
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1572, in _execute_clauseelement  
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1943, in _execute_context        
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2124, in _handle_dbapi_exception 
    util.raise_(
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context        
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "D:\PythonProjects\FastAPI\Reusable\ProjectTemplate\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 736, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: text = uuid
LINE 3: WHERE "Person".index IS NULL AND "Person".id = '5076819f-2a8...
                                                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

[SQL: SELECT "Person".index, "Person".id, "Person".first_name, "Person".last_name, "Person".occupation, "Person".dob, "Person".country
FROM "Person"
WHERE "Person".index IS NULL AND "Person".id = %(pk_2)s]
[parameters: {'pk_2': UUID('5076819f-2a88-4d7e-b2bf-f9ab4734ab98')}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce.  And the error shows you are querying by id, not first or last name.

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes I found that strange also, because the conditions in the ```filter()``` method included only ```first_name``` and ```last_name```

Comment: @snakecharmerb I just edited my question for a complete error traceback

Comment: This looks like a candidate: `session.refresh(new_data)` - what is `new_data`, exactly?

Comment: @snakecharmerb in the function I have ```new_data = Person(**request.dict())``` in which request is the request body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248573/discussion-between-sean-william-and-snakecharmerb).